# How to connect two draw components in ExtJS 4.0

Tags: extjs

I have drawn two circles in ExtJS4, using draw component. I want to know how to connect those circles using line with arrow head. Is there any methods to draw such line, without drawing arrow head manually.

Thanks,
Boopathy

Comment: like this? http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html . They don't have extjs code, but you could mimic what they do.